# How to get comments' 'likes' in detailed format like posts are having in php

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

When using PHP API `posts`' `likes` comes in this detailed format

```
[likes] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Ergec Senturk
                        [id] => 614603990
                    )
            )
        [count] => 1
    )
```

but `likes` of `comments` are only given as a counted number not in detail

```
[likes] => 1
```

How can I get `comments`' `likes` in detailed format?

Edit: I'm using this to get posts

```
$facebook->api("/$pageid/feed");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found it. Here is the solution for future Googlers

```
$likes = $facebook->api('/comment_id/likes');
```

comment_id is the one in this format xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxx